# Events and Jobs Not Firing from inside Laravel Event Listener

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, event-listener

I have an event listener that creates and saves a pdf file from a record in the db.

This process completes correctly, then I log the results and wish to fire a Job or another Event and neither will run.

If I run either from a controller they execute flawlessly.

handle method looks like so:

```
/**
 * Handle the event.
 *
 * @param  SaveRecordPdf  $event
 * @return void
 */
public function handle(SaveRecordPdf $event)
{
    $record = $event->record;

    if ($this->service->publish($record)) {
        Log::info($record->published_filename . ' was stored successfully.');

        // fire publish job
        PublishFile::dispatch($record);

    }
}
```

Is there any known reason why this would be happening?

Comment: Events only work in the context of the single PHP process execution. If you fire one but the process finishes there will be nothing to process it. Perhaps look towards ShouldQueue implementation?

Comment: It implements ShouldQueue. But `queue:work` doesn't seem to pick up events that are emitted in handlers. If I run `queue:listen` it does pick them up and fire them correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Try running the following in your repository:

`composer dumpautoload && php artisan clear-compiled`